# trouble using library seasonal in R to decompose a univariate time series

Tags: r, statistics, time-series, arima, decomposition

I am trying to decompose my univariate time series of monthly electricity production in France from 1981 to 1999, using several methodes (I do not know which one is more suitable for my data), such as the X-11 method, as outlined here : https://otexts.com/fpp3/methods-used-by-official-statistics-agencies.html
Yet, it doesn't seem to work... I have tried several decomposition methods, none of them seem to work on my data.

Here is my code :

```
 library(seasonal)
 x11_dcmp <- prod_periode_1 |>
   model(x11 = X_13ARIMA_SEATS(prod_periode_1 ~ x11())) |>
  components()
 autoplot(x11_dcmp) +
   labs(title =
          "Decomposition of nuclear electricity production using X-11.")
  x11_dcmp |>
    gg_subseries(seasonal)
```

here is the error message I get :

```
 Error in components(model(prod_periode_1, x11 = X_13ARIMA_SEATS(prod_periode_1 ~  : 
   could not find function "components"
```

Also, the default approach for X_13ARIMA_SEATS is a multiplicative decomposition, how could I change it to an additive one ? Or is there another method ? Because I think an additive decomposition better suits my data, as can be shown here :

```
  plot(decompose(prod_periode_1))  # decomposition of additive time series
```

[image: additive decomposition]

```
 prod.decom <- decompose(prod_periode_1, type = "mult")
 plot(prod.decom) # decomposition of multiplicative time series
```

[image: multiplicative decomposition]

Here is the structure of my dataset for reproducibility :

```
  structure(c(22951.429, 21465.026, 19334.531, 19319.365, 19923.664, 
  21275.248), tsp = c(1981, 1981.41666666667, 12), class = "ts")
```

Thank you for your help !